# Join MySQL Tables to Display Count

Tags: mysql, sql

Firstly, I'm a beginner to MySQL and I'm still learning. I'm trying to join 2 tables to display a count. Primarily, I use 2 codes. One code to display names -

```
SELECT tag_logs.timestamp, People.Name FROM `tag_logs` INNER JOIN People  WHERE tag_logs.tag_no = People.nametag
```

Another code to display count of names -

```
SELECT tag_logs.tag_no, COUNT(tag_logs.tag_no) FROM tag_logs GROUP BY tag_no HAVING COUNT(tag_no) >= 1
```

I want to display Name and a count number, instead of a tag number and count. I attempted to join both tables by using the following code, however, I've had little luck -

```
SELECT People.Name FROM `tag_logs` INNER JOIN People  WHERE tag_logs.tag_no = People.nametag AND COUNT(tag_logs.tag_no) FROM tag_logs GROUP BY tag_no HAVING COUNT(tag_no) >= 1
```

I'm given an error when I try to call 'FROM tag_logs' a second time. Is there a way to work around this?

[I aim to make this my final result, except I should be able to see names instead of numbers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEY6f.png)

Comment: join condition is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two tables are joined using `ON` clause. You should learn joins.

```
SELECT  People.Name ,COUNT(tag_logs.tag_no) 
FROM `tag_logs`
INNER JOIN People  ON tag_logs.tag_no = People.nametag 
GROUP BY tag_logs.tag_no
HAVING COUNT(tag_no) >= 1
```

Comment: @Oloolo . . . This query has more than one issue and is not an illustration of a good way to write the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
SELECT People.Name FROM `tag_logs`
INNER JOIN People on tag_logs.tag_no = People.nametag
GROUP BY tag_no HAVING COUNT(tag_no) >= 1
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT People.Name, COUNT(tag_no)  FROM `tag_logs`
INNER JOIN People on tag_logs.tag_no = People.nametag
GROUP BY tag_no HAVING COUNT(tag_no) >= 1
```

Comment: @OloOlo added the count

Answer (score 0):

I believe the query that you want looks like this:

```
SELECT p.Name, COUNT(*) 
FROM tag_logs tl INNER JOIN
     People p
     ON tl.tag_no = p.nametag 
GROUP BY p.Name;
```

Notes:

- `COUNT(*)` is shorter than `COUNT(tl.tag_no)` and they do the same thing.
- `GROUP BY` clause now matches the `SELECT`.  If you could have people with the same names, then add `p.nametag` to the `GROUP BY`.  A version use only `GROUP BY tl.tag_no` is invalid SQL and should fail in most databases, because of the non-matching `p.Name` in the `SELECT`.
- The `HAVING` clause (`HAVING COUNT(tag_no) >= 1`) is unnecessary, because the `INNER JOIN` requires at least one match and `tag_no` is never `NULL` (because it is used for the `JOIN`).
- I introduced table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.